# Unable to create redshift connection

Tags: amazon-web-services, jdbc, amazon-redshift, amazon-redshift-spectrum

I am trying to create the redshift connection using redshift jdbc driver which I downloaded from AWS redshift cluster console. Getting below exception

```
java.sql.SQLException: The connection attempt failed.
    at com.amazon.redshift.util.RedshiftException.getSQLException(RedshiftException.java:48)
    at com.amazon.redshift.Driver.connect(Driver.java:303)
    at java.sql/java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:677)
    at java.sql/java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:228)
    at com.redshift.jdbc.test.ConnectionTest.main(ConnectionTest.java:27)
Caused by: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: connect timed out
    at java.base/java.net.PlainSocketImpl.waitForConnect(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(PlainSocketImpl.java:107)
    at java.base/java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:399)
    at java.base/java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:242)
    at java.base/java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:224)
    at java.base/java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:403)
    at java.base/java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:591)
    at com.amazon.redshift.core.RedshiftStream.<init>(RedshiftStream.java:86)
    at com.amazon.redshift.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl.tryConnect(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:101)
    at com.amazon.redshift.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl.openConnectionImpl(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:214)
    at com.amazon.redshift.core.ConnectionFactory.openConnection(ConnectionFactory.java:51)
    at com.amazon.redshift.jdbc.RedshiftConnectionImpl.<init>(RedshiftConnectionImpl.java:288)
    at com.amazon.redshift.Driver.makeConnection(Driver.java:466)
    at com.amazon.redshift.Driver.connect(Driver.java:279)
    ... 3 more
```

code :

```
String jdbcURL = "jdbc:redshift://host:5439/database";
    String user = "*****";
    String password = "****";
    
    String driver = "com.amazon.redshift.jdbc42.Driver";
    Connection connection = null;
    Statement statement = null;
    try {
        Class.forName(driver);
        connection = DriverManager.getConnection(jdbcURL, user, password);
        if (connection != null) {
            System.out.println("Connection created!");
            
        }
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        try {
            if (connection != null)
                connection.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Can anyone please help me why I'm unable to make the connection?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess `Caused by: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: connect timed out` is a key, here's a few possibilities:

- your ip is not whitelisted in redshift security group
- if the code above is exactly what you're running then
  `String jdbcURL = "jdbc:redshift://host:5439/database";` doesn't contain a correct host and database, it myst something like
  `your-cluster-name.blahblahblah.eu-central-1.redshift.amazonaws.com:5439/your-database-name` you can find this jobs url in redshift console -> cluster general info

[image]

---

**UPDATE**

---

Check your IP whitelist in security group, and remember also to check that the IP is listed for the correct port.  (the IP might already be listed, but as 5432 for Postgres)

[image]

and add your IP if it's not here
[image]

Comment: I copied the same from your mentioned point. After that getting another error.

java.sql.SQLException: [Simba](500150) Error setting/closing connection: Connection timed out: connect.

Comment: Thank you. It's working now after add the IP.

Comment: added a note about checking the port, too, which was my problem